# Prevent Discord From Updating Automatically

Tags: default-settings, application-launch

How do we prevent Discord from Updating Automatically on Linux (point in step by step)?

Comment: Why do you want it to not update?

Comment: Consider that even if you accomplish what you want, you may simply get locked out of Discord entirely.

Answer (score 9):

## How?

To prevent Discord from automatically checking for an update on Linux, you can do so per user locally by ensuring that `settings.json` exists in the user's home directory at `~/.config/discord/settings.json` and including the following specified setting within it

```json
{
    "SKIP_HOST_UPDATE": true
}
```

With no comma at end if there is no other settings already within that file, if it exists already. Otherwise, add a comma after `true` if this is not the last option in the JSON.

Next start up of Discord should now skip the update notice, allowing you to use Discord.

---

## Why?

Others are asking why you'd want this, and it could simply be out of convenience. For example, when you have a system like Arch Linux or NixOS where you upgrade the entire system manually and often all packages at the same time due to avoiding dependency mismatch issues. This includes updating Discord at the same time. In these cases, if you temporarily do not want to upgrade your system just for Discord alone, having the option to still use Discord is convenient, rather than be locked out of it, which is the result without this setting specified.

However, it is typically good to keep your system updated.

Also, at times, Discord may have updated, but the repository you use does not yet have that update available, and so you'd be blocked from using Discord until it is available and you can update.

---

#### References

- NixOS wiki: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Discord#Discord_wants_latest_version
- Arch Linux wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Discord#Discord_asks_for_an_update_not_yet_available_in_the_repository

Comment: Another very simple "why" is if you just want to respond to a discord message real quick, having to manually download & install the update then wait through the process of it downloading/installing updates again might just be something a user doesn't want it to do at that exact moment.

I think "because the end user doesn't want to do that right now" is a fair reason.

Answer (score -4):

When you open Discord, you will see a gear symbol in the bottom left corner. This represents the User Settings.
By selecting "open Discord to off" under Windows Settings, you can disable the update.

Comment: No, not connected has nothing to do with updating or not the software. And in Linux it happens even without ever running any of the installed apps.